# 2D string array to float array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have an float array which is a[][] and a temporary reading array which is b[]. I have data like this:

```
1 1 6 4 12 5 5 3 4 1 67 3 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 2 48 2 60 1 3 2 2 1 22 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 4 12 4 21 1 4 3 3 1 49 3 1 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 42 2 79 1 4 3 4 2 45 3 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
2 1 24 3 49 1 3 3 4 4 53 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 4 36 2 91 5 3 3 4 4 35 3 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 4 24 2 28 3 5 3 4 2 53 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 2 36 2 69 1 3 3 2 3 35 3 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 4 12 2 31 4 4 1 4 1 61 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
2 2 30 4 52 1 1 4 2 3 28 3 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
2 2 12 2 13 1 2 2 1 3 25 3 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
2 1 48 2 43 1 2 2 4 2 24 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 2 12 2 16 1 3 2 1 3 22 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
2 1 24 4 12 1 5 3 4 3 60 3 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

And my code is here:

```
        for( int i = 0 ; i < linecount ; i++ )
        {
            string[] b = sr.ReadLine().Split( ' ' );
            for( int j = 0 ; j < b.Length ; j++ )
            {
                a[i,j]=  float.Parse( b[ j ]); 
            }
        }
```

It gives me this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Most of this issue on the internet is about having 123124.23234 instead of 123124,23234 but my numbers are integers. How can I do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a FormatException when converting a string to a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592950/why-do-i-get-a-formatexception-when-converting-a-string-to-a-float)

Comment: a[i,j]=  float.Parse ( b[ j ], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ); 
Gave me the exact same error. With "using System.Globalization;" right? Also they are all integers.

Comment: You need to trim your b[j] value before casting as if you have multiple spaces between numbers it will generate string like "2  " and your program will fail with that exception.  Change float.Parse( b[ j ]);  to float.Parse( b[ j ].Trim());

Answer (score 0):

One of the items you are parsing to float is not just a number and may have spaces in it. You can do this to figure out which:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
{
    string[] b = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
    {

        try
        {
            a[i, j] = float.Parse(b[j]);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            var notANumber = b[j];
        }

    }
}
```

You should instead try using:

```
float.Parse(b[j].Trim()); // Remove spaces and the parse it
```

That is if you are sure you may only have spaces and no other characters. If you have other characters, you need to remove them or replace them using `Replace`. Better yet, you should check if the parse was successful then add it to the array.

Anyways you know what the issue is now.

Answer (score 0):

We can filter out anything that isn't a number by using Regex, though I'm sure there are other alternatives too

```
    const string testData = @"1 1 6 4 12 5 5 3 4 1 67 3 2 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 2 48 2 60 1 3 2 2 1 22 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 4 12 4 21 1 4 3 3 1 49 3 1 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 42 2 79 1 4 3 4 2 45 3 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
2 1 24 3 49 1 3 3 4 4 53 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 4 36 2 91 5 3 3 4 4 35 3 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 4 24 2 28 3 5 3 4 2 53 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 2 36 2 69 1 3 3 2 3 35 3 1 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 4 12 2 31 4 4 1 4 1 61 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
2 2 30 4 52 1 1 4 2 3 28 3 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
2 2 12 2 13 1 2 2 1 3 25 3 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
2 1 48 2 43 1 2 2 4 2 24 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 2 12 2 16 1 3 2 1 3 22 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
2 1 24 4 12 1 5 3 4 3 60 3 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0";

    float[] floatArray = testData.Split(' ')
                                 .Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"(\d*)").Groups[1].Value)
                                 .Select(Convert.ToSingle)
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: That is a great answer but these questions seem to be homework questions and I doubt they are at the linq level. Nonetheless, answer is good.